# Controlsfx Popover is not displaying at right location

Tags: java, controlsfx, javafx-11

I'm designing a desktop app using java & javafx (UI Library). When a user clicks on his image in the app, a list of options will be shown to him in a popover (A class from the [controlsfx](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/blob/master/controlsfx/src/main/java/org/controlsfx/control/PopOver.java) library) relative to his parent but the problem is when the user clicks first time then it displays at wrong place and after second click it goes to its original place where it should be displayed. Could someone please point out the problem.

**Code**:

```
public class PrimaryWindowController implements Initializable {
    @FXML private Circle userIcon;
    private AnchorPane userAccountPopup;

    public void showUserAccountPopOver(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if (mouseEvent.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED)) {
            if (!popOver.isShowing()) {
                popOver.setAutoFix(false);
                popOver.setArrowLocation(PopOver.ArrowLocation.TOP_RIGHT);
                popOver.setArrowSize(0);
                popOver.show(userIcon);
                popOver.cornerRadiusProperty().setValue(0);
            } else {
                popOver.hide();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**App Images:**

[image: PopOver Wrong Position]
[image: PopOver Right Position]

Comment: I see that _controlsfx_ has a [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/controlsfx-dev). Did you try there?

Comment: I checked the conversations, but none of them is relevant to my problem.

Comment: You can post your own question to the mailing list. Maybe someone will answer?

Comment: ok I will. I hope someone help me out.

Comment: What does your `FXML` look like? I am just curious.

Comment: Also, what is the parent node that you have the `PopOver` attached to?